# How to upgrade offline instance of sonarqube plugins

Tags: plugins, upgrade, offline, sonarqube

I have an instance of sonar on a machine not connected to the internet.
Spent lots of time going through sonarqube doc but do not see anything that addresses this.
The documented method is to use the web server's update center but that seems to only look to the internet for supported/available plugins.
Java and Findbugs plugins are at 2.4 with the fresh install of sonar 4.5.1 and the java plugin that can be downloaded is (executable jar file) is 2.5.1, so I'd like to get as current as I can.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps.

1. Check what plugin version is the latest for your instance on the [plugin version matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/plugin-version-matrix/) documentation page
2. Download all plugin jars you need (beware of dependencies) by following the download link on each plugin page
3. Put the jar(s) in the `SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins` directory
4. Stop SonarQube
5. Start SonarQube

This should do the job.